# How to run a post deploy script command after deploying your CRA to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, create-react-app

I've got a create-react-app which builds and deploys without any issues onto Heroku. Within that app however I have an express server I need to start up after it's been deployed. So far I can only get it to start half way through the Heroku build which means the deployment stops. I need the server to start up after the app has been deployed. The server is responsible for the webrtc functionality of the application.

Is there a heroku post deploy script I can make use of?

So far I've tried adding this to my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "postdeploy": "node ./src/server/index.js",
```

And then in my Procfile will have:

```
web: npm run postdeploy
```

But this just runs the server during the build.

Running `heroku run node ./src/server/index.js` from VS code after deployment works, but this means I'll have to run it manually every time I deploy.

Answer (score 0):

change the `postdeploy` key to `heroku-postbuild` in your `package.json` script object.

This command will run after your build is uploaded to Heroku.

Comment: As described in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#heroku-specific-build-steps, `heroku-postbuild` runs "after Heroku installs dependencies, but before Heroku prunes and caches dependencies." Therefore this is run in the one-off build dyno, not on production (i.e. live) web dynos.